# Get all strings after the 4th occurrence of the pattern is found in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Starting with a string like:

```
String=1973251922:197325192278:abcdefgh:0xfff689990:Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

A regular expression needed for matching all strings after the 4th colon ":" and assigning it for a variable in shell script like:

```
var_result="Searching done for the string:SUCCESS."
```

Comment: Please use CODE TAGS for your sample Input/outputs in your posts.

Answer (score 4):

#### Using shell (bash or POSIX)

```
$ string="1973251922:197325192278:abcdefgh:0xfff689990:Searching done for the string:SUCCESS."
$ echo "${string#*:*:*:*:}"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

`${string#*:*:*:*:}` is an example of *prefix removal*.  It removes a prefix consisting of four colon-separated strings.

The output can be saved in a shell variable:

```
$ var_result=${string#*:*:*:*:}
$ echo "$var_result"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

#### Using cut

`cut` works for this:

```
$ string="1973251922:197325192278:abcdefgh:0xfff689990:Searching done for the string:SUCCESS."
$ cut -d: -f 5- <<<"$string"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

The above selects the fifth field and all succeeding fields where fields are separated by colons.  More specifically, `-d:` tells `cut` to use `:` as the field separator and `-f 5-` tells it to select field 5 and everything after.

To save the output in a variable, we use *command substitution*:

```
$ var_result=$(cut -d: -f 5- <<<"$var")
$ echo "$var_result"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

If you just have a POSIX shell, not bash, then we need to use `echo`:

```
$ var_result=$(echo "$var" | cut -d: -f 5-)
$ echo "$var_result"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

Or, safer still, `printf`:

```
$ var_result=$(printf "%s" "$var" | cut -d: -f 5-)
$ echo "$var_result"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

#### Using sed

The following uses sed to remove the first four fields defined by colons:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^:]*:){4}//' <<<"$string"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

More specifically:

- `[^:]` matches any character except `:`.
- `[^:]*:` matches any number of non-colons followed by a colon.
- `([^:]*:){4}` matches exactly four colon separated fields.
- `s/([^:]*:){4}//` is a *substitute* command which looks for the first four colon-separated columns and replaces them with an empty string.

The following is the same but saves the result in a variable:

```
$ var_result=$(sed -E 's/([^:]*:){4}//' <<<"$string")
$ echo "$var_result"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

The following is the same but good also for POSIX shells:

```
$ var_result=$(printf '%s' "$var" | sed -E 's/([^:]*:){4}//')
$ echo "$var_result"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

Comment: The "${string#*:*:*:*:}" seems to do the job really well.
Thanks :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Following solution may help you on same.
Let's say following is the variable's value:

```
var="1973251922:197325192278:abcdefgh:0xfff689990:Searching done for the string:SUCCESS."
echo "$var"
1973251922:197325192278:abcdefgh:0xfff689990:Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.

echo "$var" | awk -F":" '{$1=$2=$3=$4="";sub(/^:+/,"");print $0}' OFS=":"
Searching done for the string:SUCCESS.
```

Comment: The result should have all strings/characters after 4th colon. i.e 
result="Searching done for the string:SUCCESS." 

The result should have the remaining strings too.

Comment: @user3269606, please check now.

Comment: echo "$var" | awk '{sub(/([^:]*:){4}/,"")}1'

Answer (score 1):

With bash regex you can say:

```
String="1973251922:197325192278:abcdefgh:0xfff689990:Searching done for the string:SUCCESS."

if [[ $String =~ ^([^:]*:){4}(.+)$ ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```